# Why My Recorded Audio Bit rate is always Zero when recording with Mediarecorder Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have an app which records Audio and saves it in SD Card.When i check the Recorded Audio's the bit Rate of the recorded Audio files are always Zero (0 kbps).The file format is MP3. Below is my code

```
 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);   

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
}

mRecorder.start();
```

Please Suggest What could be the problem and what is the solution.Thank you.

Comment: How are you determining the bitrate? is the data written to files? 0kbps would mean the files will be empty.

Comment: @Zharf when i focus on the file in my windows 7 i am able to see the bitrate.it showed as 0 kbps.and the file still plays.

Comment: I'd say it's more likely that windows just fails at measuring the bitrate, mp3s are dodgy like that, especially variable bitrate ones. Try opening the file in foobar2000 or something and see what it says. In any case, if you get a file that has playable data in it, it is most certainly not 0 kbps because that would mean the audio would take 0 bits per second which would result in an empty file...

Comment: I have opened the audio in foobar2000 and it played just fine.

Comment: @Zharf Thank you.Your comment was the answer.The Audio file is not showing the bitrate normally but when i opened it in foobar2000 it showed the Bitrate while it is playing.Thanks again.Please post the above comment as answer and i will accept the answer.

Comment: @hermanth so i will doubt forever if your file is ok.Did you try what i say?windows is good measuring any file  bitrate,as long as they have the correct extension.Third party applications,could help to read some data, and play any kind of file even with incorrect extensions, but that is not a solution but a workaround,since you should be to have a file actually understood by the system (so you are  sure it will work all around). Could you please try to change your file extension from mp3 to 3gp and check if windows can say the bitrate? As i said, with your code i got a 3gp file named as mp3

Comment: @CarlosRobles i have changed the extension and checked the bitrate but it still shows 0 kbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your specs, and **i found a solution in my system.**

Probably you just have this simple problem that i could observe:

You are using default encoder, and default outputformat. Its ok for me if you use default encoder. 
But what i can guess, is that your default output format is 3gpp, and you ar saving the file as .mp3

If you do this, many players will play it perfectly, but it almost imposible to extract any other information from the file. So, what i suggest is, change the file extension to 3gp, and check the properties.

If you have there a bitrate,  here you have your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the way you're checking the bitrate, not the code. Quite a few applications fail to report MP3 bitrate correctly, however if you observe the size of a file and you can play it using any player, you can be sure that it's *not* 0kbps, because 0 bits per second would mean the file would be empty (well, it might have some headers in it, but you wouldn't be able to play it).

For checking music files I generally recommend [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) on windows and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

Declaration

```
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private String mFileName;
```

Generate unique file name

```
private String getRecordDefaultFileName() {
        String fileName;
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "MyRecordings" + "/");
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        if (wallpaperDirectory.listFiles() != null) {
            fileName = "record" + wallpaperDirectory.listFiles().length;
        } else {
            fileName = "record" + 1;
        }

        return wallpaperDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName + ".3gp";
    }
```

Start Recording

```
private void startRecording() {
        try {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mFileName = getRecordDefaultFileName();
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("prepare() failed");
            }

            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

Strop Recording

```
private void stopRecording() {
    try {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Permissions Required in mainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Bit rate is still 0kbps :(